# How to create a default screen if there are no tableview cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to make an app that utilizes the Tableview controller to display some cells. However, my question is: is there a way to display a default screen that says something like "No items scanned" when there are no cells in the tableview? I have attached an image of the type of screen that I am trying to create. [Here is an example of what I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkq4O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITableView.backgroundView` for that.

Here's an example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    ...

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if items.isEmpty {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "No Items"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            tableView.backgroundView = label
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            return 0
        } else {
            tableView.backgroundView = nil
            tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return items.count
        }
    }

    ...
}
```